# Master-Detail KendoGrid using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, kendo-grid

Facing issues while creating a popup for an element in child Grid, as action is not passed to the child component. using the detail property of the master Grid details={Childcomponent} in Parent component. How to pass props in details for child component ?
"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-redux": "7.0.2",

Comment: Can you share code pointer?

Comment: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/advanced-features/hierarchy/   In this example for the child component,  detail={DetailComponent} is passed in the Grid of the parent component.I am trying to pass action as props in DetailComponent.